# HTML: Input YouTube Video embed link not working

Tags: html, css, laravel

Building a **laravel** app where users can also add youtube videos (embed links).

1. How to validate if the link provided by user is actually an embed youtube video link?
2. What is the correct way to inform the users about the correct youtube link(I mean for example: https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ou7rPcoqXWA
   like this.
3. When the user inputs incorrect link, it is now showing

   ErrorException thrown with message "Trying to get property '**' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\front\posts.blade.php)"

So, what should I do to let the users know the link is incorrect
AND
If they put incorrect link, it should not show-up in the view(frontend).

The input field in the form has class, name, title, placeholder(YouTube Video URL (Paste only the embed youtube code | e.g.: https://youtu.be/xBht9TG7ySw)) & type.

& this is in view blade

```
iframe src="{{$post->video}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" height="315" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) can be useful for this kind of validation.
For [client-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) validation:

```
function validateYoutubeURL(url){
    var regex=/https?:\/\/youtu(be\.com|\.be)\/.+/;
    return regex.test(url.toLowerCase());
}
```

And for [server-side validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-regex):

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
       'field_name'=> [
            'required',
            'regex:/https?:\/\/youtu(be\.com|\.be)\/.+/',
        ]
    ]);
}
```

In order to notify user about wrong URL, use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) (Server-Side validation):

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Important:

> Note: When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

For third part of your question, please post your view and controller.

Answer (score 0):

What about using **Youtube's API ?** .
After all, that would mean using some official, which is less likely to change than going with parsing some HTML page.

For more informations : [YouTube APIs and Tools - Developer's Guide: PHP](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php?csw=1)

The [Retrieving a specific video entry](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php?csw=1#Retrieving_Video_Entry) seems quite interesting : if you send a request to an URL like this one :

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/videoID
```

*(Replacing "videoID" by the ID of the video, of course)*

You'll get some ATOM feed if the video is valid; and "Invalid id" if it's not

And, I insist : this way, **you rely on a documented API**, and not on some kind of behavior that exists today, but is not garanteed.